# Storing large amount of geotiff?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, data-management

I have about one million small geotiff files of a same region at different time. This should be a small amount of data, comparing to many other GIS applications. However, storing them as separate files makes accessing the directory extremely slow.

What is the good practice to manage this kind of raster images?

Is it a good choice to import them into database, or convert them into another format?

The file name contains the time when the image is captured.

Comment: It seems to be roughly the same amount of tiles as the whole world at zoom level 10 http://tools.geofabrik.de/calc/#type=geofabrik_standard&bbox=-173.758813,-50.104766,185.175759,85.04772. That's not an uncommon amount of files. I would suggest to divide your your data directory into subdirectories by date for limiting the number of files in one directory.

Comment: @user30184 A reasonable suggestion.

Comment: One million of anything is difficult to manage in a single location (and by no means "small"). There are many ways to approach the problem, but it makes for a Question that can't have a single, objective, "best" answer. Even though you've been here a few months, you still haven't taken the [Tour], which explains how our Focused Q&A model operates. While it may be possible to [edit] the question to be less subjective, it will be a challenge to limit multiple "correct" solutions.

Comment: @Vince I do not get your point. If there are many ways to solve the problem, then you can list out what your can come out. Q&A does not mean competition. There are many questions in stackoverflow, the community and the accepted answer are not the same. It is quite normal for a question to have multiple "best" answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store them in an array database like [Rasdaman](http://www.rasdaman.com/product.php).  That would give you the ability to serve them using OGC services such as WMS, WCS, and WCPS.

The OGC services would also allow you provide different formats on request, so no need to manually convert.

Comment: Looks pretty good. I will give it a try.